# Complicated sum() with group and order by date

Tags: mysql

There are two tables:

```
* ORDER 
  - id
  - pay_type
* ORDER_PRICE
  - order_id
  - dt
  - price
```

Order price can be changed, for example:

```
order_id | price | dt  
       1 | 100.3 | 2013-10-25  
       1 | 105.7 | 2013-10-28  
       2 | 207.4 | 2013-09-13  
       4 | 98.0 | 2013-10-03
```

I can select price history for any date like that:

```
 SELECT 
o.`id`,
    (SELECT op.`price` FROM `order_price` op 
     WHERE op.`order_id`=o.`id` AND op.`dt` <= '2013-10-26'
     ORDER BY op.`dt` DESC LIMIT 1) order_price
    FROM `order` o
```

It gives me right prices for given date

```
order_id | price | dt  
       1 | 100.3 | 2013-10-25   
       2 | 207.4 | 2013-09-13  
       4 |  98.0 | 2013-10-03
```

But i need the sum of the second column (no matter what order number, only one number - 405.7 in this case).

Is there a solution for such a situation? There can be thousands of orders, so i think it will be wrong to sum records outside the mysql. Maybe it's the wrong all the way from the start and i need other structure? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: before trying i'd like to know why you need the sum of all historically changed prices. what's the point of that information?

Comment: This query produces two columns, not three.

Comment: also, why can the price of a order change? orders are individual entities in time and should have a fixed price

Comment: The OP wants the sum of all orders at their 'current' price

Comment: Yes, it's my fault about third column - it is more virtual, added as a row comment here.

Comment: Price can change because of order's type - it's touristic service and some price factors can change - number of people, slightly different service type, service provider organisation and its price, currency exchange price and so on. Also we have in Russia floating fuel tax and many things like that.

Comment: And the price history we need to know because of accounting tasks (for example, order has 3 price changes and 4 payments parts - program should give the payed and unpayed sum for each day). @Strawberry gave the solution that works in my project, thanks to him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the core query should look more like this...

```
      SELECT o.order_id
           , op.price
           , op.dt
        FROM orders o 
        JOIN order_price op
          ON op.order_id = o.order_id
        JOIN 
           ( SELECT order_id, MAX(dt) max_dt FROM order_price WHERE dt < '2013-10-26' GROUP BY order_id ) x
          ON x.order_id = op.order_id 
         AND x.max_dt = op.dt;
```

...which can be rewritten this way, to give totals

```
SELECT o.order_id
     , SUM(op.price) price
     , op.dt
  FROM orders o 
  JOIN order_price op
    ON op.order_id = o.order_id
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT order_id, MAX(dt) max_dt FROM order_price WHERE dt < '2013-10-26' GROUP BY order_id ) x
    ON x.order_id = op.order_id 
   AND x.max_dt = op.dt
 GROUP
    BY order_id,dt
  WITH ROLLUP;
```

...or this way

```
SELECT SUM(price) total 
FROM
 ( SELECT o.order_id
       , op.price
       , op.dt
    FROM orders o 
    JOIN order_price op
      ON op.order_id = o.order_id
    JOIN 
       ( SELECT order_id, MAX(dt) max_dt FROM order_price WHERE dt < '2013-10-26' GROUP BY order_id ) x
      ON x.order_id = op.order_id 
     AND x.max_dt = op.dt
 ) z;
```

...or just pull the total at the application level.